# Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, jst

I've created Rails 4.2 project and tried to use Backbone for frontend.
But when I try to use JST for template, I've got the below error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JST is not defined
```

Of course, I included the correspond require sets in application.js file as below.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require hamlcoffee
//= require backbone
//= require backbone.marionette
//
//= require_tree ../templates/
//= require ./myapp
//= require ./models
//= require ./views
//= require ./controllers
//
//= require_tree .
```

And the file that I've used JST is as below.

```
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = (template, data) ->
  console.log "rendering template #{template}"
  if (!JST[template])
    throw "Template '#{template}' not found!"
  JST[template](data)
```

Here is my gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'marionette-rails'
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.7'
gem 'haml_coffee_assets'
gem 'execjs'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

As you can see, I am trying to use Rails 4.2 for Backbone combination.
So, I hope to know whether Rails 4.2 does not support Backbone JST file, or if I need what to make JST active.

Please help me!

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I'm now in trouble for JST undefined error.

Comment: No, I mean, _where_ do you get the error from?  Is it a Ruby error?  Or a Javascript error?

Comment: It's javascript error. When I run the Rails app, I am getting error via javascript console.

Comment: Does Rails 4 support Backbone JST even?

Comment: I mean the JST itself is undefined on running server, and not care about the whole templates parsing.

Comment: Are your JST files named correctly? In my app I am using .jst.ejs for sprockets

Comment: JST[template] , At there, JST itself is undefined, so JST file name is the next problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've got the cause of the JST undefined error. 
It's because the JST file path (in my case, path = JST["backbone/apps/" + template] ) goes to wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade `sprockets-rails` gem to version `v=2.3.3`.

It helps for me.

Comment: Does this mean that JST is deprecated in Sprockets 3.0.0 ?